# Update Post Meta for Arrays -- Remove/Replace Single Value from Multi Dimensional Array

Tags: array, post-meta

I am trying to unset/remove then replace/update a single value from a post meta field, but my code for array_push() and unset() are removing all of the values from each array.

Here are the two halves of the code I am currently using.

First, to find and remove the old value:

```
 $ID = $_GET["post_id"];
 $old = $entry["85"];
 $old_meta = array();
 $old_meta = get_post_meta($old,'_website',false);

 if(in_array($ID, $old_meta[current][items])){ 
       unset($old_meta[current][items][$ID]); 
  }

 update_post_meta($old,'_website',$old_meta);
```

Second to append the new value to the appropriate location:

```
$port = $entry["24"];
$new_meta = array();
$new_meta = get_post_meta($port,'_website',false);
$new_meta[content][items] = array();
array_push($new_meta[content][items],$ID);
update_post_meta($port,'_website',$new_meta);
```

It works to unset and insert the correct value, but any other values that were there (for both updating or unsetting) in the meta[current][items] array are removed

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what are you trying to do, but you do some strange stuff in your code. What is `$old = $entry['85']` (is it some post id)? Why are you setting `$old_meta = array()` if you assign new value right after that? And what is `current` and `items` (did you define such constants)? Also... What is structure of your meta currently?

Comment: `if(in_array($ID, $old_meta[current][items])){` - is `$ID` a key or a value inside `$old_meta`? Because `in_array` checks to see if it is a value - but in the next line of code you use `$ID` as a key.

Comment: Try adding a `print_r($new_meta)` under `$new_meta = get_post_meta($port,'_website',false);` and post the results.

Comment: This is for a form plugin, so it is editing the array using $entry objects, the 'current' and 'items' constants are defined by their theme. The array is holding post IDs, and the $ID var is the current user's post ID, which is to be removed from the old array, and added to the new.

Comment: I'll take it that by "array is holding post IDs" you mean the IDs are held as values, and not keys. That being the case `unset($old_meta[current][items][$ID]);` will not work, as there is no [$ID] key to unset.

Comment: Defined by their theme? Whose theme? A plugin and a theme are different things. And if either are setting constants called (lower-case) `content` and `items`, that's pretty poor work.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense that I'm unsetting the whole key. I'm not used to working with multidimensional arrays, so this is new to me. Would array_push still work though?

Comment: Doing this to help someone out, their theme is called Website (its from codecanyon) I've never worked with it before, and yes it seems like this would have been a whole lot easier to just use a single custom field for each option.

Comment: I still advise you to try print_r().

Comment: I'm trying, the form plugin redirects after submission. From what I am viewing in the db it just shows identical values, but the key is completely empty

Comment: This should be moved to stack it seems like a PHP question.

Comment: Here is the array from the first part http://pastie.org/8112933 it is broken when I did unset. If we don't get any answer I will try moving it to stackoverflow

Comment: After I run the array_push function it looks like this http://pastie.org/8112956